# GitLab CI - Restart service on remote host

Tags: gitlab

I have a GitLab pipeline that deploy a site and need to restart fpm service.

```yaml
    stages:
      - deploy
    
    Deploy: 
      image: gotechnies/alpine-ssh
      stage: deploy
      before_script:
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
      script:
        # other steps
        - ssh forge@$SERVER_IP -o "SendEnv=FORGE_PHP_FPM" -o "SendEnv=FORGE_SUDO_PWD" 'bash -O extglob -c "(flock -w 10 9 || exit 1\n  echo 'Restarting FPM...'; echo "$FORGE_SUDO_PWD" | sudo -S service $FORGE_PHP_FPM reload) 9>/tmp/fpmlock"'  
    variables:
        FORGE_PHP_FPM: php8.1-fpm
        FORGE_SUDO_PWD: $PRODUCTION_SUDO_PWD
    only:
        - master
```

`$PRODUCTION_SUDO_PWD` is added on gitlab variables and marked as *protected*.
My problem is with this line:

```bash
    - ssh forge@$SERVER_IP -o "SendEnv=FORGE_PHP_FPM" -o "SendEnv=FORGE_SUDO_PWD" 'bash -O extglob -c "(flock -w 10 9 || exit 1\n  echo 'Restarting FPM...'; echo "$FORGE_SUDO_PWD" | sudo -S service $FORGE_PHP_FPM reload) 9>/tmp/fpmlock"'
```

I want to restart `php8.1-fpm` service but each time I run the pipeline I get:

```
[sudo] password for forge: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for forge: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

As far as I know the `SendEnv` should pass the value of the variable and if I remove the bash command and just add `echo $FORGE_SUDO_PWD` it print the value.
What am I missing?

Comment: Got the same problem here